# Chrome update 61.0.3163.79 high cpu usage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, css, google-chrome

After Chrome latest update to V61.0.3163.79, my website gone crazy and cause high cpu usage.
Everything was fine until I relaunched Chrome for the changes to take effect.

My website is built with Angular1, Angular Material, requireJS, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of debuggin, I figured out the problem is caused by setting `direction: ltr` in a CSS property applied to `body`.

I replaced css direction by putting the `dir="rtl"` attribute on `body` instead, and CPU usage goes to 0.

I don't know why using CSS rather than the attribute would cause the problem, but making the change fixed it.

Comment: Have you created a [mcve] and reported the bug to the Chromium project?